# Real time web screen collaborating app using javascript or C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, conferencing

I need to create a page which can be shared across multiple users. Means while doing some stuff on my page, that should be broadcast to all the users who are joining me that time. At the same time they can also do some stuff. Something like web conferencing. I need to either use javascript or C#. Is there any API or javascript plugins or any other libraries that I can use? If there then please tell me. I don't need to share desktop just need to share only one part of a web page or only one section only like you can assume I have a particular division, there I have a canvas. On that canvas, I will type or draw something that should be broadcast to everyone.

Comment: Signalr would be one technology to research. http://signalr.net/

Answer (score 1):

`SignalR` is an open source technology built by two Microsoft employees and leverages C# and JavaScript (there is a jQuery plugin for the script side).

A good example to get you rolling would be [ASP.NET MVC 3 Real Time Collaborative Apps with SignalR](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/780/real-time-collaboration-aspnet-mvc-signalr).